# Traveling via Dubai without Visa

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, iranian-citizens, dub

I want to go to Tehran from New York. I have separate ticket. New York to Dubai and Dubai to Tehran. Both from Emirates with 23 hours distance.
I have an Iranian passport
I don't have any luggage. Should I take Visa? I have only two days remaining and impossible to take visa.
I don't want to leave the airport
I just want to be at airside to do my next flight
Can I follow Check in process on airside?

Both my flight are in the same terminal - terminal 3.

Comment: If you run the [IATA visa app](http://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/find_visa_requirements.aspx) on the Emirates.com website, it says that you can transit without a visa: Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit time of 24 hours. However, there is other information returned that makes it unclear whether that is true or not.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.uae-embassy.org/visas-passports/non-us-citizens:

> 3- Transit Visa ( 96 hours )
>
> The Embassy does not issue Transit Visa, You should contact the airline company that will fly you to the UAE and enquire from them about the possibility of traveling to the UAE without prior visa.

This is from a section that applies to citizens of countries that are not on an earlier list.  Iran is not on that list, so I assume that this applies to you.

Comment: Thank you
But I dont want to leave the airport or even change the Terminal and I dont have any luggage.
All I want to know is that is there any process to only get the boarding pass?

Comment: @Seyed In many countries, it is necessary for some countries' citizens to get a transit visa even if their travel plans do not require them to pass passport control.  In any event, you should speak with the airlines involved.  In many airports, there are check-in desks for transit passengers in the "airside" area; if there is no such desk then you can probably check in with the gate agent.